# Best canvas resolution when drawing in Krita (not for printing)

Tags: resolution, ppi, krita, zoom

**Introduction to the problem**

I just started graphic design and the first program I used was Inkscape for vector graphics. In Inkscape, when you are working within a project, you can zoom all you want without losing quality. On the other hand, in Krita, the printing size and ppi must be really large in order to be able to zoom within the project without losing significant resolution.

At the moment, I am just interested in posting on Instagram. Hence, no need for a massive resolution (I've been using 1800x2100 with 350ppi).

**Question**

Is there a way of having a .svg behaviour when working within Krita and zoom "all" I want *(or at least not losing a significant amount of resolution when zooming)* without having to compromise the output file resolution *(most likely a .png)*?

Comment: No you can not get painting functions then. 1800*2100 is hardly massive. Ist about the size of a typical midrange monitor. PPI is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Its also worth noting that the pixel dimensions dont grow much from what you have as typically there is no need to increase to more than double what you have as the image is viewed from further away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Krita is developed for painting. Many raster image editing tasks go well, too. You expect vector graphics. To draw it you must insert a vector layer. There you can draw and edit Bezier curves and preset shapes like circles which are freely scalable like in Inkscape or Illustrator.

I guess you would like to see painting tools working as vectors. Unfortunately most of them work only in painting layers (=bitmap).

Do not expect advanced functionality. Vector graphics toolset is rudimentary But at least vectors exist and you can copy and paste stuff between Inkscape and Krita because they both use SVG. Read this for more details: https://docs.krita.org/en/user_manual/vector_graphics.html

In theory painting tools could be vectors which are rendered as accurately as needed to bitmaps for the screen or printing. Nobody has implemented such complex vector objects. As Bezier curves or other elementary vector shapes a rich brush stroke would generate thousands or tens of thousands small paths. It can be made to happen to some degree in Illustrator or Inkscape, but the number of the shapes become soon intolerable.

An alternative way to scale bitmap paintings to bigger size without making them pixelated nor unsharp is to use an image enlargening program. Smilla is a quite well working piece of freeware and there are many commercial ones,  for example On1 Resize. They guess often succesfully what should be kept as thin and sharp and what is going to be a smooth gradient. Try them.

BTW. Do not paint for Instagram. Use as high resolution as your computer system and storage possibilities allow. Publish downscaled low resolution versions in web.

Comment: it might not make any difference that the layers are vectors if the publishing pipeline does not care.

Comment: Even when using vector layers in Krita they come out as pixelated... Is this the normal behaviour?

Comment: Yes, it's rendered to current image resolution . A vector shape can look very coarse if you zoom in the screen. But you can resize the image to bigger pixel dimensions and the vectors do not become unsharp like bitmap patterns. Try to draw a vector curve into 200px x 200px image and scale to 1000% t. The curve becomes as sharp as 2000 x 2000 allows